# Symfony 6 - Redirect after login without security.yml

Tags: forms, authentication, symfony, redirect

I have a login form for admin page.
I made this form with the maker and it works fine.

In my LoginController, i have this code :

```
$form = $this->createForm(LoginType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dd($form);
            return $this->redirectToRoute("danger-zone_admin");
        }
```

Here is my LoginType :

```
$builder
        ->add('username', TextType::class, [
            "label" => "Identifiant",
            "required" => true,
        ])
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
            "label" => "Mot de passe",
            "required" => true
        ])
        ->add("submit", SubmitType::class, [
            "attr" => [
                "class" => "btn btn-primary mt-4 btn-success"
            ],
            "label" => "Connexion",
        ]);
```

But, when form is submitted, i cant enter in my if.. and, i am not redirect to the right page.
To do the the right redirection i added in the security.yml, theses lines :

```
 form_login: 
                login_path: "danger-zone"
                check_path: "danger-zone"
                enable_csrf: true
                username_parameter: login[username]
                password_parameter: login[password]
                default_target_path: /danger-zone/admin
```

I dont understand why i cant enter in my if ! And i prefer redirect with the LoginController instead of security.yml. And, if i dont use the redirection in security.yml, i am redirected to the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont understand why i cant enter in my if

Because in Symfony the route that you define as a `login_path` is a little bit special.

From the [Symfony Security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#form-login) documentation:

> Don't let this controller confuse you. Its job is only to render the form: the `form_login` authenticator will handle the form submission automatically.

Meaning that `$form->isSubmitted()` will always be false.

A little further down below there is what you're looking for:

> If you want to control the URL the user is redirected to on success
> `<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account">`

Comment: Thanks four your answer.i did not see this part of text "Don't let this controller confuse you(...)".